# Google API - DocumentList - Create a shared link

Tags: google-api

Using the Document List API v3.0, I'm already creating a document. But now I want to share it privately using a shared link.

The protocol guide indicate that I should build a POST request like this one:

```
POST /feeds/default/private/full/<resource_id>/acl
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: OAuth <access_token>

<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
    term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>
  <gAcl:role value='writer'/>
  <gAcl:scope type='user' value='new_writer@example.com'/>
</entry>
```

But I have a problem with the Scope. The guide list 4 of them:

- user — a user's email address. => I want a link, I don't even know the email address of the person who'll access the document at the end of the process.
- group — a Google Group email address. => I use no group.
- domain — a Google Apps domain. => I use no domain.
- default — publicly shared with all users. => I don't want the document to be public.

So what scope should I use to have a private document accessible with a sharing link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've understood yet, I need to use the default scope, and then restrict the role to a specific key.

```
POST /feeds/default/private/full/<resource_id>/acl
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: OAuth <access_token>

<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
 term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>
  <gAcl:withKey key='dummy_key'>
     <gAcl:role value='writer'/>
  </gAcl:withKey>
  <gAcl:scope type='default'/>
</entry>
```

The Google [API Documentation doesn't explain at all](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ACLKeys) what's supposed to go in the key attribute. But the good news is that I just put a random string and the file apear to be accessible with the shared link, without beeing accessible to the whole public.

The document is now accessible with the following URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/<untyped_ressource_id>/edit?hl=en_GB
```

For the reccord, if I wanted to have the document accessible to the public ( referenced, etc. ) I would simply remove the withKey Part:

```
POST /feeds/default/private/full/<resource_id>/acl
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: OAuth <access_token>

<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
 term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>
  <gAcl:role value='writer'/>
  <gAcl:scope type='default'/>
</entry>
```

Comment: Great question and even better answer! Did you ever figure out how to delete the rule?:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502756/remove-a-shared-link-to-a-google-resource