# Remove a shared link to a google resource

Tags: google-api, google-docs-api

As a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445837/google-api-documentlist-create-a-shared-link) how can I remove access to a document when I have established a shared link?

I would have assumed it was something like this (where I set the role to 'none') but that doesn't work:

```
POST /feeds/default/private/full/<resource_id>/acl
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: OAuth <access_token>

<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
 term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>
  <gAcl:withKey key='dummy_key'>
     <gAcl:role value='none'/>
  </gAcl:withKey>
  <gAcl:scope type='default'/>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a DELETE request to the ACL url, as explained at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#removing_sharing_permissions

Comment: Thank you!  In my case it was a DELETE to /feeds/default/private/full/<resource_id>/acl/default